# using subprocess for the youtube-dl for automatic song list downloading

Tags: python, json, youtube, subprocess, youtube-dl

From the following code, I want to query each line which contains a song name (a line from a file "playlist.txt") from the google search engine, then based on the results I am taking the youtube link and using the youtube-dl, I am extracting the audio.

When i run the link which the results hold,GOOGLE blocks that claiming a unusual traffic from my computer system.Any method to counter that

I have used sleep to keep a time lapse between the requests.

I want to know how to rectify that error

I think changing the user agents or using proxies might be useful to avoid automated search detection.So, I wanted to know how to change my code to achieve that

```
import urllib
import json as m_json
import re
import time
import subprocess
from random import randint
import getpass
playlist=open('playlist.txt','r')
songs = playlist.readlines()
song_num = 1
for song in songs:
   query = song
   query = urllib.urlencode ( { 'q' : query } )
   response = urllib.urlopen ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&' + query ).read()
   json = m_json.loads ( response )
   results = json [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]
   for result in results:
       title = result['title']
       url = result['url']
       if re.search(r'www.youtube.com',url):
           print ( title + '; ' + url )
           print "DOWNLOADING",title
           decoded_url=urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8')
           print decoded_url
           subprocess.call(['youtube-dl','-o','/home/'+getpass.getuser()+'/Videos/playlist%('+title+").(ext)s","--extract-audio","--audio-format","mp3",decoded_url])
           break;
   print song_num
   time.sleep(randint(10,15))
   song_num+=1
```

output

```
DOWNLOADING <b>Black Sabbath Iron Man</b> - YouTube
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rT4KpfiFcNc
[youtube] rT4KpfiFcNc: Downloading webpage
[youtube] rT4KpfiFcNc: Extracting video information
[youtube] rT4KpfiFcNc: Downloading DASH manifest
ERROR: Error in output template: unsupported format character '(' (0x28) at index 73 (encoding: 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: What is your terminal output when you run this?

Comment: @Lawrence I added it! the same output for each song(or line) from the file

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to do this via python, but FYI you can likely do all of it via a single youtube-dl command line, with the  `gvsearch`, `--match-title`, and `--reject-title` options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `url` is malformed. If you look closely, you have:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DrT4KpfiFcNc
```

but the proper Youtube URL format is:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rT4KpfiFcNc
```

You should try to decode the URL before calling the `youtube-dl`. Something like this:

```
url=urllib.unquote(result['url']).decode('utf8')
```

Additionally, your output format is invalid; you want simply

```
'-o', '~/Videos/playlist%(title)s.(ext)s"
```

`%('+title+").` is adivising youtube-dl to look for a *property named after the title*, and to boot, missing an `s` after `)`.

Comment: this worked quite well, but i am getting a new error.

http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DrT4KpfiFcNc
DOWNLOADING <b>Black Sabbath Iron Man</b> - YouTube
[youtube] rT4KpfiFcNc: Downloading webpage
[youtube] rT4KpfiFcNc: Extracting video information
[youtube] rT4KpfiFcNc: Downloading DASH manifest
ERROR: Error in output template: unsupported format character '(' (0x28) at index 73 (encoding: 'UTF-8')
1

Comment: after decoding If i use that link to download using youtube-dl from terminal it works fine! but not through the script

Comment: Please update your question and include the new terminal output, complete.

Comment: i am a newbie to this forum! thank u for ua suggestions @Lawrence

Comment: how to randomise a list of user agents and proxy servers for this to avoid automated searches detection